# Strange bug of date_modify function in DateTime class

Tags: php, datetime

I use the native PHP DateTime class for adding days to dates. But when dealing with negative dates, I encountered a strange bug. Depending on the millennium added or a day or two. Example:

```
$date_one = date_create("-1000-12-27");
date_modify($date_one, '+1 day');
//Return DateTime Object ( [date] => -1000-12-29 00:00:00 ) 

$date_two = date_create("-2000-12-27");
date_modify($date_two, '+1 day');
//Return DateTime Object ( [date] => -2000-12-28 00:00:00 ) 

$date_three = date_create("-3000-12-27");
date_modify($date_three, '+1 day');
//Return DateTime Object ( [date] => -3000-12-29 00:00:00 )
```

That is, depending on the parity of the millennium issue, or December 28 or December 29. Why is this happening? What is the problem?

Comment: Because php has no knowledge of that time. See [Epoch start/end for Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: @Andrew See http://php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php Specifically the bit about **+-292 billion years**

Comment: It looks to me like this may be related to this outstanding bug in PHP `https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69205` and `https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67993` Maybe you could add this situation to the bugs to make sure this also gets checked. Seems like this has been a bug forever as I tested it in PHP `5.3/5.4/5.5/5.6`